# Could not read config file while deploying static content in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, static-content

It shows error in FileResolver file.

[image]

Comment: Try running with `-vvv` flag to see more detailed error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check `{your_theme_dir}/etc/view.xml` file, 
then, if empty, copy it from Magento_blank theme and run `setup:static-content:deploy` again.